# logical indexing in structure field

Tags: matlab, indexing

I have a data structure and would like to extract the reaction times for a condition. Both are stored in the same structure. Where is my error in the code? I do not understand it?

```
rt = EEG.event.EMG(strcmp({EEG.event.condition}, 'condition stress'))
```

Error message:

> Intermediate dot '.' indexing produced a comma-separated list with 382 values, but it must produce a single value to perform subsequent indexing
> operations.

`EEG.event.EMG` is a structure field that contains reaction times of participants.

`EEG.event.condition` is a structure field that contains info on the respective condition.

In this case I want to select reactions times for "condition stress" through logical indexing.

Comment: We don’t know what any of those variables are, so cannot help you with how to index them. You should also copy-paste the full error message into your post.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry & Thanks for your comment. I edited the initial post. Hope this is more of help.

Answer (score 0):

So if `EEG.event` is an array, then `{EEG.event.condition}` is a cell array with  the condition for all the events. The result of `strcmp` therefore is the index into `EEG.event`, not `EEG.event.EMG`. You’d index as follows:

```matlab
index = strcmp({EEG.event.condition}, 'condition stress');
rt = EEG.event(index).EMG;
```

(separated into two statements for clarity.)